# Error running software updater

Tags: 14.04

Whenever I run the software updater tool I get the error dialog shown below. Any idea what might be the cause? There's definitely no problem with my internet connection.

[image]

### Update

As suggested, I ran `sudo apt-get update` on the command-line and got the following error

> W: Failed to fetch file:/Packages  File not found

### Output of find command

Here's the output of the `find` command that @NikTh requested

```
$ find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dell.list

     1  deb file:/ /
     2  deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04 _Trusty_ - Build amd64 LIVE Binary 20140620-04:25]/ trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty-oem.list

     1  deb http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-oem public
     2  deb-src http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-oem public

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list

     1  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
     2  # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
     3  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/trusty-dell.list

     1  deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-dell public
     2  deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ trusty-dell public

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java-trusty.list

     1  deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
     2  # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main

/etc/apt/sources.list

     1  
     2  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
     3  # newer versions of the distribution.
     4  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
     5  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
     6  
     7  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
     8  ## distribution.
     9  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
    10  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
    11  
    12  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    13  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
    14  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    15  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
    16  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
    17  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
    18  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
    19  
    20  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
    21  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
    22  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
    23  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
    24  ## security team.
    25  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
    26  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
    27  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
    28  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
    29  
    30  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
    31  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
    32  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
    33  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
    34  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
    35  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    36  deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    37  
    38  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
    39  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
    40  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
    41  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
    42  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
    43  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
    44  
    45  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
    46  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
    47  deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
    48  deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
    49  
    50  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
    51  ## 'extras' repository.
    52  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
    53  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
    54  # deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
    55  # deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
    56  
    57
```

Comment: Please open the terminal profile preferences and goto the tab "Scrolling". Change the output to "Unlimited". Then issue this command. `find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \; ` . Edit your question and provide here ALL the results. Also provide the FULL RESULTS of `sudo apt-get update` command.

Comment: @NikTh done, see above

Comment: Please post **full results** of `sudo apt-get update` too. I see this is a DELL PC with Ubuntu pre-installed(certified hardware) and for that, it would be wise to contact with Dell support/forums also.

Answer (score 2):

On my Dell XPS 13, the offender was
(from the first line of /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dell.list):

```
deb file:/ /
```

Commenting out or removing this first line will allow apt-get update to run without the "W: Failed to fetch file:/Packages File not found" issue.

Comment: Same error on my Dell XPS 13.